# Automator Javascript - "Choose From List" return values

Tags: javascript, macos, applescript, directory, automator

I'am trying to create a Service which allow user to choose a folder, then show a list with options where he can choose from and based on the selected items, automator should create a folder for each chosen item in the list.

What I got so far:

1) Asked for Finder item => this allows user to choose a folder

2) JS where I create the options for the list

```
function run(input, parameters) {

 var array = ["PDF", "LINKS", "PERSMAP", "SCHUIMKARTON", "INSPIRATIE"];
 var arrayLength = array.length;

 return array;
}
```

This gives me the following output when already when I run:

[image]

3) Added another JS-script Where I return the input (this returns only the selected items)

[image]

4) ... This is where I'am stuck. How do I create a folder now for each selected option from within the list?

> Complete overview in next atachment

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `chooseFromList` command in your JavaScript instead of the "**Choose from List**" action and another "**Run JavaScript**" action.

You an use `.map()` to loop from the selected items.

Here's the script:

```
function run(input, parameters) {
    thisApp = Application.currentApplication()
    thisApp.includeStandardAdditions = true
    var destFolder = input[0];// the destination folder
    var array = ["PDF", "LINKS", "PERSMAP", "SCHUIMKARTON", "INSPIRATIE"];

    theseNames = thisApp.chooseFromList(array, {withPrompt: 'Which folders to create?', multipleSelectionsAllowed:true});
    if (theseNames == false) {return}; // exit this script because user cancelled

    // (for each selected name then create the folder if this name does not already exists in the destination folder), return path of these sub-folders to the next action
    return theseNames.map(function(thisName) { 
        newFolder = destFolder + "/" + thisName + "/";// concatenation of the destination folder and an item in theseNames
        $.NSFileManager.defaultManager.createDirectoryAtPathWithIntermediateDirectoriesAttributesError(newFolder,false,$(), $());
        return newFolder;
    }); 
 }
```

---

**Update**

To create some subfolders within the new folder, use conditions **(if name equal some name)**, like this:

```
function run(input, parameters) {
    thisApp = Application.currentApplication()
    thisApp.includeStandardAdditions = true
    var destFolder = input[0];// the destination folder
    var array = ["PDF", "LINKS", "PERSMAP", "SCHUIMKARTON", "INSPIRATIE"];

    theseNames = thisApp.chooseFromList(array, {withPrompt: 'Which folders to create?', multipleSelectionsAllowed:true});
    if (theseNames == false) {return}; // exit this script because user cancelled

    f_m = $.NSFileManager.defaultManager;
    // (for each selected name then create the folder if this name does not already exists in the destination folder), return path of these sub-folders to the next action
    return theseNames.map(function(thisName) { 
        newFolder = destFolder + "/" + thisName + "/";// concatenation of the destination folder and an item in theseNames
        f_m.createDirectoryAtPathWithIntermediateDirectoriesAttributesError(newFolder,false,$(), $());
        if (thisName == "PDF") { // create folder1 and folder2 in the PDF folder
            f_m.createDirectoryAtPathWithIntermediateDirectoriesAttributesError(newFolder + "folder1",false,$(), $());
            f_m.createDirectoryAtPathWithIntermediateDirectoriesAttributesError(newFolder + "folder2",false,$(), $());
        }
        if (thisName == "INSPIRATIE") { // create folderX in the INSPIRATIE folder
            f_m.createDirectoryAtPathWithIntermediateDirectoriesAttributesError(newFolder + "folderX",false,$(), $());
        }
        return newFolder;
    }); 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks already for this solution, is it also possible when user e.g. chooses "inspiration" to create some subfolders WITHIN this folder? (e.g. PDF, LINKS, INSPIRATIE are selected and within PDF I want 'folder1', 'folder2' and in INSPIRATIE I want 'folderX')

Comment: This is useful for anyone wondering how to use JavaScript within Automator because documentation seems to be non-existent, so thanks for this!